# Why is there extra output when using newline as IFS?

Tags: linux, bash

I was testing the output for different values of IFS using the code below.

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n'

export $IFS

for i in $(ls -la);
do
  echo $i;
done
```

But for newline as IFS the following things were also printed before the intended output. Why does it show this output?

```
declare -x DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-xwjTMGqSe7,guid=b8543bd3ba7dbc5ca284b0ce5741ccff"
declare -x DESKTOP_SESSION="default"
declare -x DISPLAY=":0"
declare -x GDMSESSION="default"
declare -x GDM_LANG="en_US.utf8"
declare -x GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE="/usr/share/applications/atom.desktop"
declare -x GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID="19896"
declare -x GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT="stderr"
declare -x GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS="JS ERROR;JS LOG"
declare -x GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID="this-is-deprecated"
declare -x GPG_AGENT_INFO="/run/user/1000/keyring/gpg:0:1"
declare -x LANG="en_US.utf8"
declare -x NODE_ENV="production"
declare -x NODE_PATH="/usr/share/atom/resources/app.asar/exports"
declare -x OLDPWD
declare -x PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games"
declare -x SHELL="/bin/bash"
declare -x SHLVL="1"
declare -x SSH_AGENT_PID="2218"
declare -x SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh"
declare -x WINDOWPATH="7"
declare -x XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP="GNOME"
declare -x XDG_DATA_DIRS="/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/"
declare -x XDG_MENU_PREFIX="gnome-"
declare -x XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/1000"
declare -x XDG_SEAT="seat0"
declare -x XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP="default"
declare -x XDG_SESSION_ID="1"
declare -x XDG_VTNR="7"
```

Comment: You probably want to read [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the dollar sign in the `export` command.

Due to your assignment, `$IFS` will expand to a newline, which, without quotes, will simply be dropped by the shell, leaving the `export` command on its own with no arguments.

And according to `help export`:

```
export: export [-nf] [name[=value] ...] or export -p
  [...]
  If no NAMEs are given, or if `-p' is given, a list of
  all names that are exported in this shell is printed.
  [...]
```

Which is exactly what happens.

To fix that, just leave the `export` command off altogether, as it's not required in this case (thanks, [kojiro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418413/kojiro)).

Comment: This is a correct answer to the question asked, but I don't think OP actually needs to export IFS at all.

Comment: @kojiro, so it would seem.

Comment: @kojiro You're right, it's not required here. Thanks for spotting that. :)